# Unable to push git repo to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

here are the steps :

1. git add .
2. git status
3. git commit -m "initial commit"
4. git push -u origin

**This works perfectly**

1. heroku login
2. heroku create --stack cedar
3. **git push heroku master** --`ERROR`

HERE IS THE `LOG:`

```
D:\boot>git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 1711, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1522/1522), done.
Read from remote host heroku.com: Connection reset by peer
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blooming-hollows-3183.git'
```

**What are the refs missing?**

Comment: You can try to pull the latest changes of that branch locally and push them again..this happens with heroku sometime ..is it happen to you first time?

Comment: yes actually i am pushing first time and it happens like this

Comment: Try re-installing Heroku Toolbelt (it's like a problem with authentication)

Comment: use git add -A,git commit -am "msg",git push -f heroku master, see if works or not!

Comment: I used to get "Connection reset by peer" when my net connection disconnects!